# Docs unexpectedly being deleted from elasticsearch after scraping

Tags: python, elasticsearch

For my fantasy football team, I have been scraping data from www.footywire.com, which I am then trying to import into Kibana via elasticsearch. All of this is being written in Python 2.7 with BeautifulSoup.

So for each player, I am scraping info like the number of possessions that player had, the opposing team (etc) and which round of the competitive season it was. There is also a unique key for each item, based on the players URL and round number that was scraped.

This all works fine...all the data outputs to a .csv file, and I can see that it is all coming out how I want it. If a player hasn't played this season, they are skipped.

The problem is that only one entry for each player that has been scraped is being imported into Kibana (via elasticsearch); the rest are being deleted. I know this from Sense:

[image]

When I go into Kibana, I can see that there are only 617 items, instead of the expected 6300+.

The only hint that I get from the logs is a "no handlers could be found for logger elasticsearch.trace" message. Where might things be falling down?

Note: I don't know what kind of code might be relevant here, as the actual scraping itself works. It's just the importation in elasticsearch that is problematic.

**EDIT:** I'm using Logstash to import from elasticsearch into Kibana. Nothing has been setup in logstash for this project, so its just using the default settings with the new scrapy project was started.

```
[settings]
default = footywire.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = footywire
```

Comment: How do you import your CSV into Kibana/ES?

Comment: Oh right. It does it automagically through Logstash

Comment: Can you share your Logstash config?

Comment: You dont need to use logstash to import into kibana. Logstash is meant to pipeline logs to elasticsearch or any other store for that matter

Comment: Also are you setting id of the player as its name? because elasticsearch needs unique ids for each doc in a type. Query elasticsearch for all records and look at their version numbers, if they arent 1 and you havent modified data, then this is the issue.

Comment: @rajat: Good call. I had setup a unique key, and then not specified that item in my settings. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly pointed out by @rajat, elasticsearch needed unique ids for each doc that is sent to it. I had incorrectly set this up.